# mysql optimization / how to use index tip...?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

if this is my USERS table

```
user_id 
user_fname  
user_lname  
user_email  
user_pass   
user_verified   
user_city   
user_joined 
user_lastlogin  
user_about
```

i set user_id as PRIMARY (is an auto incremental value)

thaen, should i set user_email as INDEX? other suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add indexes to columns that are often used in query conditions, ordering, joining. 
There is no point in adding an index to a column that doesn't play any role in the query.

If you have thoughts about optimizing a query, at first, you should check it out in [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html)  query to see how complex the query is.

Comment: that's interesting, i never heard EXPLAN before (im self taught sql wannabe)...so how can i use the EXPLAIN? directly in phpmyadmin append in it to a test query?

Answer (score 2):

You should use indexes when your table is searched more frequently than it gets updated. If your table is searched using `user_email` very often, then you may use indexes on that column.

Remember, if `user_email` field gets updated more often than being used in a search condition, then it will ultimately lead to a performance overhead.

Go [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) for further insight.

Comment: gerat, i got it... definitely user_email is used often to search among users, and user_verified is searched every time i need a query to list all verified users.. i think i got the concept! thanks!!!